# Difference between "feels" and "is feeling" in the following case

Tags: grammar, tense

> I'll ask her to phone you as soon as she feels better.
> I'll ask her to phone you as soon as she's feeling better.

Personally the first one sounds better, but the second sentence is found in a grammar book without explanation for its intended meaning. Is there any difference?

Comment: In some dialects the [present continuous](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/present-continuous) is used excessively. IMO the first is better, because this will be at a particular moment in time.

Comment: IMO the second is more natural, because _feeling better_ can be a gradual process, not a sudden change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When talking about feelings, saying "*I feel*" or "*she feels*" can be used to a *permanent* feeling or way of thinking. For example, "*I feel this movie is too violent for children*". That 'feeling' is unlikely to change.

"*I am feeling*" would be used to refer to *current* feelings. For example, "*I am feeling hot*". It is more likely that such feelings would change.

Your example uses what is usually considered a *comparative* adjective - 'better'. If you feel ill, you may *gradually* improve, feeling 'better' each day. However, "better" is unusual in that it is also used idiomatically to mean you have recovered after an illness.

So, both "I *am feeling* better" and "I *feel* better" could mean that you have improved from a previous state, **or** that you have fully recovered. You can also say "I *am* better".